# Estimate relationship between X and Y in R

Tags: r, function, relationship

I want to estimate the relationship between X and Y (from data m) using P (see below) at 100 equal points over (0, 10). How can I do this using R?

```
> m
      X        Y
1     0.5      6.0
2     1.5      5.0
3     2.5      6.7
4     3.5      7.1
5     4.5      6.1
6     5.5      8.1
7     6.5      8.0
8     7.5      7.9
9     8.5      8.0
10    9.5      6.0
```

(1)

```
 P=function(x,X,Y,sigma){
  # x = point to evaluate our estimate.
  # X = vector of observation X values
  # Y = vector of observation Y values
  # sigma = standard deviation.

  weights = rep(0,length(X)) 
  sumweights = 0              
  smooth = 0                  

  for(i in 1:length(X)){

    weights[i] = dnorm(x,mean=X[i],sd=sigma)


    sumweights = sumweights + weights[i]

    smooth = smooth + weights[i]*Y[i]
  }

  return( smooth/sumweights )
}
```

Comment: What? This has got to be the most unclear question I have ever seen.

Comment: @nograpes I edited the question, let me know if it needs more clarification...

Comment: @Titi90 - now it makes even less sense! Explain what you are trying to do in a bit more detail please!

Comment: @thelatemail Sorry for the confusion. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Are you talking about a regression model to describe the relationship between `X` and `Y`? Something like `lm(Y~X,data=m)` ?

Comment: @GaryWeissman Yes, unless there's another way of estimating a relationship between X and Y

Comment: @Titi90 It needs more clarification.

Comment: @nograpes See latest edit

Comment: @Titi90 see my answer below about fitting a model to your data...does this answer your question?

Comment: @GaryWeissman how is the function P being accounted for in the estimation?

Comment: @Titi90 What the function P has to do with your question is precisely, I think, what no one understands. You're going to have to explain that further.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you said " I want to estimate the relationship between X and Y" which sounds like trying to fit a function to your data set.  One way to explore data of unknown relation is to plot it and try and guess at a mathematical relationship between variables.  For example:

```
m <- read.table(header=T, text='
       X        Y
     0.5      6.0
      1.5      5.0
      2.5      6.7
      3.5      7.1
      4.5      6.1
      5.5      8.1
      6.5      8.0
      7.5      7.9
      8.5      8.0
     9.5      6.0')

with(m,plot(X,Y))
```

Now try fitting a linear regression to your data.

```
lm_xy <- lm(Y~X,m)

abline(lm_xy,col='blue')

summary(lm_xy)
```

This doesn't look like a good fit, but you can play around with `lm`, `nls` and other packages to look for a better model.

For example, try:

```
pn_xy <- nls(Y ~ a*(X - b)^2 + c, start = c(a=0.05, b=8, c=8),data=m)

lines(m$X,predict(pn_xy,m$X),col='red')

summary(pn_xy)
```

You can see the different models here:

[image]